# Creating TypeScript type definitions for a library that exports factory function

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to create type definition file for a library. The library is shipped to clients long time ago, so I can not change its code.

I'm using TypeScript 2.*

The library package exports a single factory function (using default export); The user can create instances of the lib using that factory function. 
What i use for lib.d.ts is

```
declare var _createLib: (config: Object) => Promise<Lib>;
export default _createLib;

export interface Lib {
    version: string;
}
```

And then I'm trying to use it in TypeScript like:

```
import LibFactory from 'lib';

LibFactory(configObject).then((actualLib: Lib => {
    // do some magic here
});
```

But it fails, because Lib type (the that of actualLib) is not defined.

There are two ways I can make it work, but I'm not sure these are proper solution:

*1) Import all from Lib*

```
import * as Lib from 'lib';

Lib.default(configObject).then((actualLib: Lib.Lib => {
});
```

2) Import default as some name, and any other type from the lib as named import

```
import {default as Factory, Lib as Lib} from 'lib';

Factory(configObject).then((actualLib: Lib=> {
});
```

I'm missing something? Is there a better way to create and use type definitions in that case?

Answer (score 1):

You'r right, in this case you should import both pieces. But this syntax should work as well for you:

```
import Factory, { Lib } from 'lib';

Factory(configObject).then((actualLib: Lib=> {
});
```

Also, if factory has right definition, you can omit specifying `actualLib`'s type:

```
import Factory from 'lib';

Factory(configObject).then((actualLib => {
});
```

Typescript will know it's type.

Comment: However when transpiled  this results to JS like

  Factory.default(configObject)

which throws 

default is not a function

Comment: Your `factory.js`, not `factory.d.ts`, must have default export. What I provided, is just literally shorter rewrite of your `import {default as Factory, Lib as Lib} from 'lib';` If this line works, my answer will work too.